# Integrating SAML based SSO with Third party service provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, spring-security-saml2

We have to integrate third party SP for SSO. Our application is  a wrapper in spring(not springboot) and it has authentication/authorization module calling backend service using mongo as DB.
Now the requirement is to integrate SSO  SAML based SP with a third party.  The third party has given docs which asks to have IDP. In the provided requirement from SP, Nameid assertion has to be persistent ,unique and opaque and can be userid of client application (our application).
I believe we have to have an IDP  like SSOCircle or Okta  or some open source IDP in order to integrate with SP. And I think we can write a separate springboot SAML IDP   and expose api to our legacy spring for login to SP.
Flow  as I understand:

1. User from our portal  access the third party SP website or API.
2. Third party SP  will redirect the user to our IDP to log in .They will save NameId(UUID mapping of userids or userids) at their end which they will pass as SAML request along with other assertions.
3. Once User is successfully logged in , our IDP will redirect the user to third party SP with success response.

My questions :

1. Can  (or should we )we bypass IDP ? I guess this would mean we write SAML IDP on our own. Please let me know my best options  or whether this is a good idea to go without IDP and write our own equivalent.If we can't, I would assume we have buy paid proprietary or use open source IDP.
2. Nameid (unique, persistent, opaque) assertion  : This is one of SP requirement.If we have to use IDP (which I think), and it SP consumer assertion requirement is  to use persistent Nameid to be passed.It should be unique, persistent and opaque . So we are thinking that UUID mapping of userids  in SAML request to IDP should be OK. If  we go like this,  we have to store UUID mapping in DB as nameid assertion .  Do we have to use  just our portal userids as nameIds or UUID in DP -SP integration to satisfy requirement? Please comment what approach is right.
3. Nameid persistence restrictions at IDP end as well as at SP end:There is one  bottleneck at our end.Our IT security team would probably not allow NameId persistent mapping UUID forever due to security concern, In that case NameId mapping will change at our end. How should be address this if we have to use UUID as nameid?
4. NameId provisioning :  when user from our portal request to login to SP - Would it be passed to SP as login request and then SP constructs  saml request and pass nameids assertions to IDP  ? If yes ,what is best approach for nameids be passed to SP as login request ? If no, how will SP know what UUID  to pass in SAML to IDP? How will we address this  if the mapping  nameid are UUIDs which could change due to security concerns?  . Another thing is though nameid is mentioned is mentioned as "persistent" in requirement but in the examples of requirement doc they are showing `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified` . I think thats probably a mistake in doc. [?].
5. Any sample SSO SAML IDP (client ) application which we can refer which is close to above 1 ) and 2)?

Answer (score 0):

> Can (or should we )we bypass IDP ? I guess this would mean we write SAML IDP on our own.

No, you can't. If the 3rd party acts as a SAML Service Provicer, you need to or act as a SAML Identity Provider. Building your own implementation is quite a big tasks and you may either use an SAAS-based IdP like SSO Cirle (keep in mind that your customer needs to accept where the user idenity data is stored) or deploy your own SAML IdP. There are payed products/service or free-of-charge. Open source need not mean free-of-charge , that's often misunderstood.

If you need a SAML IdP anyway, you may think of making your own app act as a SAML SP as well to leverage authentication of the IdP.

Which NameId format to use is kind of agreement. The SAML spec propose the usage of specific NameId format for specific purposes, e.g.

- 'transient' NameId format is meant to be used for SSO flow only.
- 'persistent' is meant to be used when you want to link identities of different identity silos together

The SP may use the value of the NameId value in the subject to find a user's profile or to perform auto-federation (build a profile on its side). It could also use attributes from the SAML attribute statement to achieve the same. Many SP implementations offer this.